# laravel help. Eloquent. Items that have comments > 2

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

im new to laravel.
I have got a problem with getting the objects of:
Items that have comments > 2.

Just to be clear. one item have many comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
$items = $items->filter(function($item)
{
    return $item->comments()->count() > 2;
});
```